# how to get output of left join using full join operation?

Tags: sql

how to get output of left join using full join operation?

Comment: This is likely a homework or interview question, and as such, you should at least show us the full question, along with whatever you might have already tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share if there is anything specific you want to get answer about by sharing input and expected output. FYI, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` is first evaluated as `FULL OUTER JOIN` and then records from either `LEFT` or `RIGHT` side table (depending on the join type) is preserved to show the final result.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output / tracebacks). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

create table dept(
  deptno     number(2,0),
  dname      varchar2(14),
  loc        varchar2(13),
  constraint pk_dept primary key (deptno)
)

create table emp(
  empno    number(4,0),
  ename    varchar2(10),
  job      varchar2(9),
  mgr      number(4,0),
  hiredate date,
  sal      number(7,2),
  comm     number(7,2),
  deptno   number(2,0),
  constraint pk_emp primary key (empno),
  constraint fk_deptno foreign key (deptno) references dept (deptno)
)

insert into DEPT (DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC)
values(20, 'RESEARCH', 'DALLAS')
insert into DEPT (DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC)
values(30, 'SALES', 'CHICAGO')
insert into DEPT (DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC) 
values(40, 'OPERATIONS', 'BOSTON')
select*from dept;

insert into emp
values(
 7839, 'KING', 'PRESIDENT', null,
 to_date('17-11-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),
 5000, null, 10
)

insert into emp
values(
 7698, 'BLAKE', 'MANAGER', 7839,
 to_date('1-5-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),
 2850, null, 30
)

insert into emp
values(
 7782, 'CLARK', 'MANAGER', 7839,
 to_date('9-6-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),
 2450, null, 10
)

insert into emp
values(
 7566, 'JONES', 'MANAGER', 7839,
 to_date('2-4-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),
 2975, null, 20
)
insert into emp
values(
 7788, 'SCOTT', 'ANALYST', 7566,
 to_date('13-JUL-87','dd-mm-rr') - 85,
 3000, null, 20
)
insert into emp
values(
 7902, 'FORD', 'ANALYST', 7566,
 to_date('3-12-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),
 3000, null, 20
)

insert into emp
values(
 7369, 'SMITH', 'CLERK', 7902,
 to_date('17-12-1980','dd-mm-yyyy'),
 800, null, 20
)
insert into emp
values(
 7499, 'ALLEN', 'SALESMAN', 7698,
 to_date('20-2-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),
 1600, 300, 30
)
insert into emp
values(
 7521, 'WARD', 'SALESMAN', 7698,
 to_date('22-2-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),
 1250, 500, 30
)

output:
select *from dept
full join emp
on dept.DEPTNO=emp.DEPTNO
where dept.DEPTNO=emp.DEPTNO
union
select *from dept
full join emp
on dept.DEPTNO=emp.DEPTNO
where emp.DEPTNO is null;

Comment: can also solve using select *from dept 
full join emp 
on dept.DEPTNO=emp.DEPTNO
where dept.DEPTNO is not null